# Loading Parquet data using schema / using XSD to validate XML

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xsd, parquet

I have some XML files that I need to store in a structure given in an XSD file, in parquet/avro.  The XML/XSD files contain duplicate tag headings ( might appear twice) so I have opted to use Parquet as Avro does not support this.

I want to take an XML check that it is valid (against an XSD file) and where ever an xsd element exists that is not present in the XML, I want to simply store that value as NULL.

The way I see it I have two options:

1) Check xml against xsd with scala, if valid then (somehow) fill any differences with NULL and store as parquet.

2) Check xml validity then use the schema of the parquet version of the XSD file to insert paquet data of the xml file.

I'm not entirely sure how to do either so I would appreciate a pointer to ensure that I am not wasting my time going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find my desired solution but it is extremely easy to use unix for the validation.

```
xmllint -schema xsdfile xmlfile --noout
```